# My resource dictionary is omitting my label from being showed

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a wpf app and I am messing with loading themes (light and dark), I made two simple resource dictionary files which are created in a shared assembly:

Dark Theme (same structure for the light theme, but with different color values):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF1E1E1E" x:Key="Background"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextColorBrush" Color="White"/>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In my main application, App.xaml I am referencing my 2 theme dictionaries as such

```
<Application x:Class="Foo.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Foo.Core.WPF;component/Resources/Dictionary_DarkTheme.xaml" x:Name="DarkTheme"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Foo.Core.WPF;component/Resources/Dictionary_LightTheme.xaml" x:Name="LightTheme"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The way I am setting up the resources based on which theme I am choosing is done in the App.xaml.cs

```
public enum Skin { Light, Dark }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static Skin Skin { get; set; }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            ChangeSkin(Skin.Light);
        }

        public void ChangeSkin(Skin newSkin)
        {
            Skin = newSkin;

            if (Skin == Skin.Dark)
                ApplyResources(Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].Source.ToString());
            else if (Skin == Skin.Light)
                ApplyResources(Resources.MergedDictionaries[1].Source.ToString());
        }

        private void ApplyResources(string src)
        {
            var dict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(src, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) };
            foreach (var mergeDict in dict.MergedDictionaries)
            {
                Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(mergeDict);
            }

            foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
            {
                Resources[key] = dict[key];
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally, my main window. Since I want these particular styles to be global I am not using any keys to identify them.

```
<Window x:Class="Foo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="hello"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But my main issue is that the Label control doesn't show up in my application. I can see my background change color appropriately but my label control is just gone! What am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add all theme ResourceDictionaries from the start to `Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries`, i.e. start with empty `Application.Resources`:

```
<Application x:Class="Foo.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then change the theme by replacing `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` with the current theme:

```
private void ChangeSkin(Skin skin)
{
    ResourceDictionary theme = null;

    switch (skin)
    {
        case Skin.Light:
            theme = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Foo.Core.WPF;component/Resources/Dictionary_LightTheme.xaml") };
            break;
        case Skin.Dark:
            theme = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Foo.Core.WPF;component/Resources/Dictionary_DarkTheme.xaml") };
            break;
    }

    if (theme != null)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(theme);
    }
}
```

---

When changing themes only means to replace Colors and Brushes, you may also move your Styles to `Application.Resources` and use `DynamicResource` in the Style Setters.

```
<Application x:Class="Foo.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextColorBrush}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Background}"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then your theme ResourceDictionaries would only contain Color and Brush resources:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF1E1E1E" x:Key="Background"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextColorBrush" Color="White"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thank you again and I see your point. What I wanted to do is make these dictionaries accessible to other projects within the Solution. That way any new WPF project would reference the shared project where these dictionaries are and then they could get the same "skins".